# Java REGEX <script> tag removing from URL

Tags: regex, xss, html-sanitizing, removeall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove JavaScript with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041377/remove-javascript-with-regex)

How can i remove all content between `<script`.... and ... `</script>`?
If I write:

```
s = s.replaceAll("<script.+</script>", "");
```

It removes everything between the first `<script` until the last `</script>`, but i want to remove from the first `<script` until the first `</script>`
please help

Comment: if this is supposed to be a security measure then it won't work

Comment: @OttoAllmendinger - as a security measure, I don't think it can possible be made fool-proof, but it can certainly be made to mangle and invalidate any attempt to bypass a security measure, and it can be made to gracefully and effectively remove properly formatted script

Answer (score 2):

It's generally a bad idea to use regexes to parse HTML — there are infinitely many corner cases, and it's a lot of effort to catch them all (what if your input is `<!-- <script> --> foo <!-- </script> -->`?) — but to answer your very specific question: change `+`, which is a "greedy" quantifier that consumes as much as it can, to `+?`, which is a "reluctant" quantifier that consumes as little as it can.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html.

Comment: Thx, tried with the DOM parsing, but did not work for me) I am not allowed to use third party libraries, so trying to do that with regex

Answer (score 0):

I have suggested this in the past:

```
<\s*script.*?(/\s*>|<\s*/\s*script[^>]*>)
```

Use the "single-line" or "dotall" compiler switch, as appropriate to your language or tool.

For more information, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8043367/561690

In response to comments, I have made changes that should do nothing more than to make it even harder to get something by it successfully. As for any whitespace between `<` and `script` - I wouldn't put it past someone to ignore that part of the recommendation (Standard?) when building a parser, in the name of making it more flexible, so I'll leave it as part of my answer!

Comment: Your `\s?`s seem very odd to me. Whitespace between the `<` and `script` will invalidate that tag; and whitespace between the `</script` and `>` is not limited to a single character.

Comment: In this you may be absolutely correct. However, the user is brand-spanking new, and asked a question that is for all practical intents and purposes identical to the question I referenced - so there's the question of ROI. I'll make the changes you suggest, but I have a suspicion it won't make much difference! thanks regardless!

Comment: This will convert `<s<script></script>cript>alert(1337)</script>` to `<script>alert(1337)</script>`.

Comment: @mikesamuel - it will then convert `<script>alert(1337)</script>` to `` will it not?

Comment: @CodeJockey, If the replacement was done in a loop that looped until convergence, yes, but I don't see anything in your answer about doing the replacement in a loop.  A single global replacement is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

[OWASP Java HTML Sanitizer](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project) is an HTML sanitizer sponsored by OWASP written in Java that takes a string of HTML and whitelists tags and attributes to produce a string of safe HTML.

It's gone through multiple rounds of attack review and fits the same niche as AntiSAMY.

Full disclosure: I am a maintainer.